# Ubuntu 16.04 server auto enter root shell in recovery mode

Tags: boot, command-line, 16.04

I wanted to leverage the "recovery mode", which allows me to enter root shell without creating any normal user accounts. When it automatically enters "recovery", a second menu appears and I have to scroll down to choose "Drops to root shell" to get to prompt console. How to bypass that "Recovery menu" as I want to boot the system automatically into root shell?

Answer (score 0):

Based on this tutorial blog [How to Change Systemd Boot Target on Linux](http://www.systutorials.com/239880/change-systemd-boot-target-linux/) I *think* the answer (for 16.04+ systems, that use `systemd`) is

```
sudo systemctl set-default rescue.target
```

If you want to verify what the target does before setting it as your default, you can use

```
sudo systemctl isolate rescue.target
```

Comment: I think you misunderstand the question, my question is how to automatically comeout from 2nd screen during rescue mode.